# PHP SQL Server error tracking

Tags: php, sql

I am tracking mysql errors using the function `mysql_error` that everyone knows. But, I am accessing records from SQL Server, For that i have used all the `mssql_` functions which are provided by PHP.

One of my queries is not getting executed and am not sure where i did the mistake. Can any one please tell me, what is the exact function for SQL Server to track the DB errors(available in PHP).

```
SELECT * FROM gb WHERE postalcode like 'YO1%' OR place like 'YO1%' group by postalcode, region3 order by postalcode asc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no error function in SQL Server. Instead, use [`mssql_get_last_message()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple select sql. I would want to run this in SQL Server Management Studio, if I were you. Apart from that, try this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php#21728 where someone has tried to resolve issues using a GENERIC ERROR HANDLING Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM gb WHERE postalcode like 'YO1%' OR place like 'YO1%' group by postalcode, region3 order by postalcode asc
```

This can never work, as you are using the GROUP BY clause. You will need to specify which fields to show. So something like:

```
SELECT
    postalcode, region3
FROM
    gb
WHERE
    postalcode LIKE 'YO1%' OR place LIKE 'YO1%'
GROUP BY 
    postalcode, region3
ORDER BY 
    postalcode ASC
```